# Unmatched ) in Javascript regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

May be you can help me: 
My javascript code:

```
bbchatdecode: function(text) {  

var chars = Array(":\\)","8-\\)",":cry:",":oops:");
var replacements = Array('<img src=\"smiley-smile.gif\" alt=\":)\">','<img src=\"smiley-cool.gif\" alt=\"8-)\">','<img src=\"smiley-cry.gif\" alt=\":cry:\">','<img src=\"smiley-embarassed.gif\" alt=\"oops:\">');
for (var ic=0; ic<chars.length; ic++) {
  var re = new RegExp(chars[ic], "gi");
  if(re.test(text))
  {
   text = text.replace(re, replacements[ic]);
  }
}
return text;
}
```

But in the browser I can see:

unmatched `)` in regular expression

Comment: Are you trying to parse HTML with regular expressions?

Comment: He's doing a find-replace on text.

Comment: The code posted *should not* throw that error. Make sure that's *really* the code. Please *reduce it to a minimal test case* and mention *which browser* it occurs in.

Comment: It appears here: Firefox, Crome

Comment: @user889349 *bullpoo* That code will no throw that exception. I just ran in the web console and guess what .... *no error*. Please **make sure** that is *really* the code.

Comment: @user889349 Consider posting a demonstration to http://jsfiddle.net -- just the function above and some sample text to process.

Comment: @pst Whoops, my brain isn't working today :)

Comment: pst is correct.  There is no error in the code as posted: http://jsfiddle.net/cDRZS/

Comment: tested in ie6, firefox 7,chrome 11: works without error

Answer (score 21):

`Unmatched ) in Javascript regular expression` error occurs when some of your string contains `')'`. You need to escape this. Here is the function to do that:

```
function escapeRegExp(str) {
  return str.replace(/[\-\[\]\/\{\}\(\)\*\+\?\.\\\^\$\|]/g, "\\$&");
}
```

Comment: this regex spoils my actual regex

Answer (score 5):

Valid regexp string is: `:\\\)`. You should triple-repeat backslash in order to escape something from string. When you are constructing your regexp as raw JS (e.g. `var re = /:\)/;`) you do not to do that.

Sorry, but i can not explain why this happens for now.

Comment: `new RegExp(":\\)")` is "valid": `":\\)"` -> `:\)`

Answer (score 2):

As with one of the commentors, I don't believe thats your code (excluding the fact that you left out the object declaration).  It does't give me that error and jsFiddle makes it work if an object is declared.

I think what is going on is that is actually part of some code in another language (php, perl?) to output an object with that propery, and  the multi line string isn't working as expected.  Copy the code off of actual page, include a bit more context, and we might be able to solve your problem (if this doesn't lead you to an answer).

Answer (score 2):

let's say you have `var str='ff_!)'`  and you need `var reg = new RegExp(str, 'gi')` 
yes you will get error

```
SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /ff_!)/: Unmatched ')'
```

what you actually need is that fix:

```
new RegExp('ff_![(]', 'gi').test('ff_!(')
```

the line above return `true`

or event better this fix

```
new RegExp('ff[_][!][(]', 'gi').test('ff_!(')
```

the line above return `true` too.

solution:

```
if (/\W|[_]/g.test(str)){ //if str has any symbols
      str = str.replace(/\W|_/g, '[$&]'); //use brekits [ ] for that symbols
    }
var reg = new RegExp(str, 'gi');
reg.test('ff_!(') //return true
```

about `$&` (Specifying a string as a parameter)  you can read [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_string_as_a_parameter)

Comment: This regexp will fail with numbers. E.g.: as a result for "123 123".replace(/\W|_/g, '[$&]') will be "123[ ]123". So the more precise solution will be: str.replace(/\(|\)/g, '[$&]')